# Is it possible to migrate changes to OWD's / Sharing Rules via Changesets?

Tags: deployment, sharing, change-set, owd

Is it possible to migrate changes to OWD's via a Changesets?

If it is possible, what is the category name to look under when adding an OWD to a changeset?

Comment: I think the question should be "is there any way to deploy OWD without deploying the object and all its fields?"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but either the answer has changed or the answer was wrong.

OWD is deployed as part of the metadata of the object.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/customobject.htm

Comment: The answer has changed. This is a 5 yr old question and MUCH has changed in 5yrs on the platform.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the answer is "no." Based on the [components available listing](http://na14.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/changesets_about_components.htm), you can deploy sharing rules for individual objects but not the OWDs.

Comment: I had expected as much, I just wanted to check that I wasn't missing something. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes throgh Ant Migration its possible.

Below file Name: objectAPIName.object
ex. Incentive__c.object

Incentive
 Incentives
 
        Name
        Text
    
 Deployed
**Private**

// above we changes OWD from Public Read Only to provite

Package.xml:

B2B_Incentive__c
        CustomObject
    
    41.0

Deploy above through workbench or anttool.